# How do I get the parsed data using GSON

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, gson

So I was following this [tutorial](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/how-to-parsing-json-array-using-gson-in-android-tutorial/) and it has this method.

```
new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            Reader reader=API.getData("http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/DiIRBM4");

            Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<DoctorBean>>(){}.getType();
            beanPostArrayList = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(reader, listType);
            postList=new StringBuffer();
            for(DoctorBean post: beanPostArrayList){
                postList.append("\n heroName: "+post.getHeroName()+"\n realName: "+post.getRealName()+"\n\n");
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            Log.d("JSON Result ", postList.toString());
        }
    }.execute();
```

The Log Result would only show these values.

**JSON Result:**

> heroName: null realName: null
>
> heroName: null realName: null
>
> heroName: null realName: null

This is my JSON data

```
[
{
    "heroName": "Dr. Strange",
    "realName": "Stephen Strange"
},
{
    "heroName": "Spider-Man",
    "realName": "Peter Paker"
},
{
    "heroName": "Captain America",
    "realName": "Stever Rogers"
}
]
```

This is my **Data Model**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class DoctorBean {

    @SerializedName("heroName")
    private String heroName;

    @SerializedName("realName")
    private String realName;

    public DoctorBean(String heroName, String realName) {
        this.heroName = heroName;
        this.realName = realName;
    }

    public String getHeroName() {
        return heroName;
    }

    public void setHeroName(String heroName) {
        this.heroName = heroName;
    }

    public String getRealName() {
        return realName;
    }

    public void setRealName(String realName) {
        this.realName = realName;
    }
}
```

And this is my **API class**

```
public class API {
    private static Reader reader=null;
    public static Reader getData(String SERVER_URL) {
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                reader = new InputStreamReader(content);
            } else {
//              Log.e("error:", "Server responded with status code: "+ statusLine.getStatusCode());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return reader;
    }
}
```

I noticed that the log Result showed 3 rows, so I was thinking it was able to get the length of the array correctly. But as for the data, all was null.

Comment: The link which you are trying for get json data is giving different json as compair to your json. So You need to create POJO class as per real json response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your given [tutorial](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/how-to-parsing-json-array-using-gson-in-android-tutorial/),from [this](http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/DiIRBM4) link response is as below:

```
    [
   {
      "date":"11/8/2014",
      "auther":"nirav kalola",
      "description":"json object parsing using gson library is easy",
      "post_name":"json object parsing"
   },
   {
      "date":"12/8/2014",
      "auther":"nirav kalola",
      "description":"json array parsing using gson library",
      "post_name":"json array parsing"
   },
   {
      "date":"17/8/2014",
      "auther":"nirav kalola",
      "description":"store json file in assets folder and get data when required",
      "post_name":"json parsing from assets folder"
   }
]
```

So you need to try below POJO class for **GSONBuilder**. Replace your name with **BeanPost**.

```
 import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class BeanPost {


@SerializedName("post_name")
private String post_name;
@SerializedName("auther")
private String auther;
@SerializedName("date")
private String date;
@SerializedName("description")
private String description;

public BeanPost(String post_name, String auther, String date, String description) {
    this.post_name = post_name;
    this.auther = auther;
    this.date = date;
    this.description = description;
}

public String getPost_name() {
    return post_name;
}
public void setPost_name(String post_name) {
    this.post_name = post_name;
}
public String getAuther() {
    return auther;
}
public void setAuther(String auther) {
    this.auther = auther;
}
public String getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
}
```

Try to create **beanPostArrayList** as above pojo class arraylist. And try your code and get appropriate fields from it.

I hope its helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Create an array from response :

```
DoctorBean[] doctorBeanArray = new Gson().fromJson(response, DoctorBean[].class); // Where response is your string response
```

Then create an ArrayList :

```
ArrayList<DoctorBean> doctorBeanList = new ArrayList<DoctorBean>(Arrays.asList(doctorBeanArray));
```